# BSOD with BCCode 24 - Should I worry?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

With Chrome, Steam, and Plex Media Player already using most of my RAM, I (perhaps foolishly) started up Factorio to try and grab a blueprint out of a map someone posted on Reddit. I could see in Task Manager (usually always open on my left screen, along with MSI Afterburner, for monitoring) that Factorio was using over half the system RAM (total 4GB) when I was ready to initiate the process in-game. Everything froze up for a few minutes, even including Task Manager, before the system bluescreened with a worry-inducing error referencing Ntfs.sys.

The game had already slowed to a crawling 2 FPS due to the sheer size of the area I selected, and I'm hoping that the ensuing bluescreen was just a result of me pulling the last straw from my limited RAM (and not a hard drive issue—I've already swapped the system drive in this machine once this year).

Windows presents the following information if I check the reliability report and open this incident's details:

```
Source
Windows

Summary
Shut down unexpectedly

Date
‎7/‎25/‎2017 03:59

Status
Report sent

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033

Extra information about the problem
BCCode: 24
BCP1:   00000000001904FB
BCP2:   FFFFF880031934B8
BCP3:   FFFFF88003192D20
BCP4:   FFFFF8800131DD89
OS Version: 6_1_7601
Service Pack:   1_0
Product:    256_1
Bucket ID:  X64_0x24_ntfs!NtfsGetDiskGeometry+1df
Server information: <snipped, looks like a GUID of some kind>
```

System specs are mostly last-decade chic:

- Gigabyte GA-MA69VM-S2 board
- AMD Phenom 9750
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- Gigabyte GTX 750 Ti
- System drive: ST3000DM001 (relevant only because of its reputation)

I'll leave SeaTools checking the drive overnight, I suppose. Any words of wisdom from the Windows wizards of Superuser would be much appreciated. I found all manner of forum threads on Google referencing BCCode 24, but the results all seemed to be inconclusive as to what the cause was and if action was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this crash: [Bug Check 0x24: NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x24--ntfs-file-system):

> The NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM bug check has a value of 0x00000024. This
>   indicates a problem occurred in ntfs.sys, the driver file that allows
>   the system to read and write to NTFS drives.

Microsoft lists in its documentation the following possible causes:

> One possible cause of this bug check is disk corruption. Corruption in
>   the NTFS file system or bad blocks (sectors) on the hard disk can
>   induce this error. Corrupted hard drive (SATA/IDE) drivers can also
>   adversely affect the system's ability to read and write to disk, thus
>   causing the error.

Also try these suggestions to fix it:

> - Try disabling any virus scanners, backup programs, or disk defragmenter tools that continually monitor the system.
> - You should also run hardware diagnostics supplied by the system manufacturer related to the storage sub system.
> - Use the scan disk utility to confirm that there are no file system errors. Right click on the drive you want to scan and select
>     Properties. Click on Tools. Click the Check now button.

So check the HDD with a manufacture tool, run chkdsk.exe and disable all third-party tools/drivers that access disk(s) often.

Comment: Marking as accepted since it answers the question "Should I worry?" by way of providing diagnostic steps that will answer it. Thanks!